# Mocking class parameter that returns a mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery, laravel-5.1

I am new to unit testing and trying to test a controller method in Laravel 5.1 and Mockery.

I am trying to test a `registerEmail` method I wrote, below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
use Mailchimp;
use Validator;

/**
 * Class ApiController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    protected $mailchimpListId = null;
    protected $mailchimp = null;

    public function __construct(Mailchimp $mailchimp)
    {
        $this->mailchimp = $mailchimp;
        $this->mailchimpListId = env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID');
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function registerEmail(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        $email  = $request->get('email');

        try {
            $subscribed = $this->mailchimp->lists->subscribe($this->mailchimpListId, [ 'email' => $email ]);
            //var_dump($subscribed);
        } catch (\Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed $e) {
            return Response::json([ 'mailchimpListAlreadySubscribed' => $e->getMessage() ], 422);
        } catch (\Mailchimp_Error $e) {
            return Response::json([ 'mailchimpError' => $e->getMessage() ], 422);
        }

        return Response::json([ 'success' => true ]);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to mock the Mailchimp object to work in this situation.
So far, my test looks as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class HomeRouteTest extends TestCase
{

    use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function testMailchimpReturnsDuplicate() {
        $listMock = Mockery::mock('Mailchimp_Lists')
            ->shouldReceive('subscribe')
            ->once()
            ->andThrow(\Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed::class);

        $mailchimp = Mockery::mock('Mailchimp')->lists = $listMock;

        $this->post('/api/register-email', ['email'=>'duplicate@email.com'])->assertJson(
            '{"mailchimpListAlreadySubscribed": "duplicate@email.com is already subscribed to the list."}'
        );
    }
}
```

I have phpUnit returning a failed test.

> HomeRouteTest::testMailchimpReturnsDuplicate
>   Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method subscribe() from Mockery_0_Mailchimp_Lists should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Also, if I assert the status code is 422, phpUnit reports it is receiving a status code 200.

It works fine when I test it manually, but I imagine I am overlooking something fairly easy.

Comment: Hi. What is your full path to `Mailchimp` class? Not alias but full path with namespace.

Comment: I'm using the skovmand/mailchimp-laravel package here: https://github.com/skovmand/mailchimp-laravel.  The Mailchimp class is in the global namespace, and require_once's a lot of other classes in the file as well.

Comment: You are mocking Mailchimp_Lists, but i don't see that class being loaded anywhere in your controller.

Comment: It's not included in the controller, the Mailchimp class file require_onces Mailchimp_Lists in it.   I think by mocking Mailchimp and setting the lists parameter on it to be a mock, that should work around the problem?  Obviously something's still wrong with it.

Comment: Maybe an expansion on the question: how would you test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself.  I eventually moved the subscribe into a seperate Job class, and was able to test that be redefining the Mailchimp class in the test file.

```
class Mailchimp {
    public $lists;

    public function __construct($lists) {
        $this->lists = $lists;
    }
}

class Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed extends Exception {}
```

And one test

```
public function testSubscribeToMailchimp() {
    // create job
    $subscriber = factory(App\Models\Subscriber::class)->create();
    $job = new App\Jobs\SubscribeToList($subscriber);

    // set up Mailchimp mock
    $lists = Mockery::mock()
        ->shouldReceive('subscribe')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true)
        ->getMock();

    $mailchimp = new Mailchimp($lists);

    // handle job
    $job->handle($mailchimp);

    // subscriber should be marked subscribed
    $this->assertTrue($subscriber->subscribed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockery will expect the class being passed in to the controller be a mock object as you can see here in their [docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/getting_started/simple_example.html):

```
class Temperature
{
    public function __construct($service)
    {
        $this->_service = $service;
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
$service = m::mock('service');
$service->shouldReceive('readTemp')->times(3)->andReturn(10, 12, 14);

$temperature = new Temperature($service);
```

In laravel IoC it autoloads the classes and injects them, but since its not autoloading `Mailchimp_Lists` class it won't be a mock object. Mailchimp is requiring the class atop it's main class `require_once 'Mailchimp/Lists.php';`

Then Mailchimp is then loading the class automatically in the constructor

```
$this->lists = new Mailchimp_Lists($this);
```

I don't think you'll be able to mock that class very easily out of the box. Since there isn't away to pass in the mock object to Mailchimp class and have it replace the instance of the real `Mailchimp_Lists`

I see you are trying to overwrite the lists member variable with a new Mock before you call the controller. Are you certain that the lists object is being replaced with you mocked one? Try seeing what the classes are in the controller when it gets loaded and see if it is in fact getting overridden.

Comment: I was able to confirm that the controller isn't receiving a mocked version of the Mailchimp class.  The big difference between my test and your example is that I am using the integration test features for testing a controller, and you're instantiating a class.